# Which is faster: $("li").last() or $("li:last-child")?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, which is faster to execute: `$("li").last()` or `$("li:last-child")` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Though both are different in what they do but here is result I got from jsperf:

http://jsperf.com/li-last-vs-li-last-child

[image]

**$("li").last()**

```
28,752
±8.59%
fastest
```

And

**$("li:last-child")**

```
21,930
±4.01%
24% slower
```

So `$("li").last()` is faster.

---

FYI `$("li").last()` selects the absolute last element whereas `$("li:last-child")` selects ***every*** last element in a series of grouped elements. That also makes it obvious that `$("li").last()` should be faster which it is.

Comment: How would they give different results?

Comment: @KevinBurke: Imagine in your document you haev multiple `ul li` elements. `$("li").last()` will select the very last `li` of the very last `ul` whereas `$("li:last-child")` will give you last `li` of every `ul` element on the page.

Answer (score 4):

**The two are not equivalent.**

`.last()` will always return a single element; `:last-child` potentially matches multiple elements if each has a different parent (and thus is the last child for its respective parent).

That said, `.last()` is slightly faster if you only have one parent for all of the elements you're selecting from.

Comment: @Thilo - I was; I had just posted the initial statement while I was formulating the rest.