# Before cloning last div inside cover div, I need to update the name attribute

Tags: jquery, html

Before cloning last div inside cover div, I need to update the name attribute so that I don't end up with duplicated names. How can I do it? I'm did as much as I could but stack at one point. My current JQ might look silly so happy to change it if you provide better one since I'm new in JQ.

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<div id="label-field-cover">
    <div><input type="text" value="" name="size-label-1"></input></div>
    <div><input type="text" value="" name="size-label-2"></input></div>
    <div><input type="text" value="" name="size-label-3"></input></div>
</div>
```

**JQ**

```
   //Clone last div
    var $cloned = $('#label-field-cover div:last').clone();

    //Get the content of cloned div
    var clonedContent = $cloned.html();

    //This echos: ""<input name="size-label-3" value="" type="text">""
    console.log(clonedContent);

    //I need to change name="size-label-3" to name="size-label-4" somewhere here first

    //This adds cloned element after last div
    $('#label-field-cover div:last').after($cloned);
```

Comment: since you have a new last element once you do the .after command you could just call `$('#label-field-cover div:last').attr("name", "size-label-4")`

Comment: $('#label-field-cover div:last').after($cloned).attr("name", "size-label-44444"); -> changes the name attribute of div not the input which is what I want.

Comment: Yea just noticed that in my test switch that to `$('#label-field-cover div:last input').attr("name", "size-label-4");` the selector needs to target the child element input field

Comment: Now it clones cloned div into last div :)

Comment: you would add this line after `$('#label-field-cover div:last').after($cloned);`

Comment: I got you. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should answer it so that I can accept the solution for others to see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're appending a new element calling last will select that element and you can rename it using the attribute tag

```
//Clone last div
var $cloned = $('#label-field-cover div:last').clone();

//Get the content of cloned div
var clonedContent = $cloned.html();

//This echos: ""<input name="size-label-3" value="" type="text">""
console.log(clonedContent);

//I need to change name="size-label-3" to name="size-label-4" somewhere here first

//This adds cloned element after last div
$('#label-field-cover div:last').after($cloned);

//Add this in
$('#label-field-cover div:last input').attr("name", "size-label-4");
```

adding the `$('#label-field-cover div:last input')` input value here causes it to target the child input element of the last div element inside the label-field-cover object

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use last() method instead of div:last because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663452/which-is-faster-li-last-or-lilast-child).
Something like:

```javascript
var $cloned = $('#label-field-cover div').last().clone();
```

What you want to achieve is simple to do it with jQuery:

```javascript
var new_name = $cloned.children('input').attr('name', 'size-label-4');
```

jQuery is awesome, so you can do something like this:

```javascript
$cloned.children('input').attr('name', 'size-label-4');
$('#label-field-cover div').last().after($cloned);
```

I hope it works, I didn't test it xD

Comment: It is changing DIV's name not input's.

Comment: You're right. Sorry, mate ;) I think it works now. Let me know.

Comment: Nearly there. It is now ignoring DIV wrapper around the input element so cloning only <input ../> rather than <div><input .. /></div>

Comment: @Culyx - Already solved it so I accepted his however +1 for you too.

Answer (score 0):

there ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/vimes1984/4aXdV/22/

```
   //Clone last div
   var $cloned = $('#label-field-cover div:last').clone();

   //Get the content of cloned div
   var clonedContent = $cloned.html();

   //This adds cloned element after last div
   $('#label-field-cover div:last').after($cloned);
   //first we get the newly added attribute name
   var clonedattr = $('#label-field-cover div input:last').attr('name');
   //regex to match the diigits in it
   var clonednumber = clonedattr.match('([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])');
   //first digit returned we change from string to a actual number
   var getnumber = parseInt(clonednumber[0]);
   //add one to it   
   var addone = getnumber += 1;
   //check to make sure it's actually added   
   console.log(addone);
   //reapply to the last INPUT the attribute with the added number...
   $('#label-field-cover div:last input').attr('name', 'size-label-' + addone);
```

this will grad the last added input and add one to the value then change the name to the new added value